# How to allow insecure connections using Tiny Rest Client?

Tags: c#, rest-client

I have a site that can connet using https but not http. There is no certificate installed in server, so, when connected using htts, a warning is shown.

If using a browser, I can allow to browse anyway, however, if I use Tiny Rest Client, a certificate  not valid exception is thrown.

Is there a way to allow that connection using TinyRestClient? I have not found a way yet.

Thanks

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/ ? Or is this a locally hosted server? Will it be sufficient to use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: No.... it is a Web Server embedded inside a device. That is why I asked about doing that using the client, since I cannot modify the server nor installing anything in it.

Comment: Argh, that's too bad. I am not familiar with TinyRestClient, though, sorry. I tend to prefer the "more secure" path. But in this case, you seem to be stuck with plain http.

Comment: Funny enough: from their examples - `var client = new TinyRestClient(new HttpClient(), "http://MyAPI.com/api");` (Mind _http_ not _http**s**_)

Comment: The server sends an invalid response if using http. The only way to receive a valid response is by mean of https.

Comment: Oh wait ... I just read again. The protocol _is in fact_ http**s** but the server has no cert? Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.". If one could make Tiny Restclient not to validate the certificate, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inject a new HttpClient that has a custom HttpHandler, you should be able to access any kind of certificate, even self signed

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
        HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
};
var http = new HttpClient(handler);

var client = new TinyRestClient(http, url);
```